# Adding a list of libraries in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a list of libraries that I an trying to add to `target_link_libraries()`. Is it possible?

```
 set(list1 x.a y.a z.a)
 target_link_libraries(main ${list1})
```

Is it a right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the usual way to do this.

To be more precise, usually the list is set by first using `find_library` to get the `x.a` location first, and then putting them in a list.